# Add custom css to vue build library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Want to create a simple library from vue project and use that in any other js framework like Angular, react.
I have created a simple project and trying to convert that into lib using the below command.

```
npx vue-cli-service build --target wc --inline-vue --name hello-world
```

This command will create js files. and one html file which contains.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="path/to/my-element.js"></script>

<!-- use in plain HTML, or in any other framework -->
<my-element></my-element>
```

here when I add my custom css that won't get applied to 
so how can I seprate css from lib and apply different css on prod readylib?

Comment: Have you tried adding your own CSS in this HTML file?

Comment: Yes but did not work

Comment: Can you show us your CodeSandbox where it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

import your css file in component file like that:

```
<style src="my-style.css" />
```

then in vue.config.js file add this code:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  }
}
```

**note**: if you haven't vue.config.js file, create that